# Missing realm constructor React Native iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm, react-native-ios, realm-mobile-platform

I am working with Realm and react native. After linking Realm with my project i am getting "Missing realm constructor" in iOS simulator. But it is working in android device perfectly. I have followed [this link](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#missing-realm-constructor). Still, it is not working.

Here is the image of the error in iOS simulator:
[image]

Whenever i am removing "import realm from "realm";" from the js file app is working in iOS simulator.

My working environment -

1. Mac mini (10.13.2)
2. VSCode (1.19.1)
3. lzma-native: 3.0.4,
4. react:16.0.0
5. react-native: 0.51.0
6. realm: 2.1.1

Please help me with this... and thank you in advance

Comment: Hi. Did you fix the issue?

Comment: If you use RNI to create your project then this solution worked http://tuntunir.blogspot.com/2018/02/react-native-missing-realm-constructor.html
and CRNA and expo do not support realm so you will face this error there.

Comment: thanks, figured the same way out (ejected from CRNA and did react-native link realm)